# Tkinter: calling destroy() during resize resets the window to original shape

Tags: python, tkinter, window-resize

In a Tkinter GUI, during window resizing at runtime, I've noticed that the removal of a widget or a frame, using `my_widget.destroy()`, resets the window size to the original shape (the one it had at the start of the resizing). I've found an identical question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767715/tkinter-w-destroy-blocks-resets-window-resize), with no solution. Couldn't find anything else online.

Is there a way of calling a destroy without interrupting the resize action and resetting the size?

Here is a sample code to test this behavior (creates an empty window of width 800, use the mouse to make it smaller than 600):

```
import tkinter as tk


class TestResize(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("800x400")
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resizing)

    def resizing(self, *args):
        self.update_idletasks()
        if self.winfo_width() < 600:
            self.frame1.pack_forget()
            self.frame1.destroy()


def main():
    root = TestResize()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't notice anything  unusual happening when I resize the window.  What platform are you seeing this on?

Comment: There are two things that might be contributing to the problem First, there's no need to call `self.update_idletasks()`. Two, when you put a binding on the root window, it will fire for _every_ window, so it's being called both for the frame (and any of its children) along with the root window.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for reading my question, I'm on Windows 10. When I resize the window and the width becomes less than 600, my window instantly goes back to 800, the initial width. The problem persists even without the `update_idletask()` and also binding the configure to the frame instead of the root window. On what platform did u try it?

Comment: I can confirm the issue on Windows 10 as well. Note that can't you always, re-_set_ the size of the window?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know it's a long time, but I just ran into this in python 3.7 on windows 10 and my workaround is to use:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930736/7281120

```
        if win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) >= 0:
            for widget in self.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()
```

to prevent destruction when the mousebutton 1 is pressed. It's a hack but it appears to work.